# Why Does This Return "cannot convert nil to string"

Tags: ruby, cucumber, pageobjects, page-object-gem

I am using almost the exact same setup of Jeff Morgan's book "Cucumber & Cheese" and I have a page object with like this

```
class NewPublicationPage
  include PageObject
  include RSpec::Matchers
  ... 
  def submit_basic_message_with_tag
    @tag = Time.now.to_i
    ...
    self.tag_entry = @tag
    # the tag ends up getting added later on down the road to a div container.
    ...
  end

  def verify_last_tag
    done_loading
    # tag_list is a div container that should contain the tag.
    tag_list.should include @tag
  end
end
```

When I run the following commands in Cucumber steps, each command with its own step, it fails saying `cannot convert nil to string`. I know it has to do with the instance variable @tag, but I'm not sure why.

```
When /^I submit a basic message with tags$/ do
  on_page(NewPublicationPage).submit_basic_message_with_tag
end

Then /^I should see the tag under Publish History$/ do
    visit_page(PublishHistoryPage) # goes to page with div container that holds tags
    on_page(NewPublicationPage).verify_last_tag #this creates the error
end
```

Comment: You didn't add code of your steps but so I'm not sure, but I would say that if the second step fails, it's because @tag is nil. Indeed in the `submit_basic_message_with_tag` function you're assigning it a value, but not in the second function.

Comment: I think you are right, so how would I grab the value of `@tag` from the `submit_basic_message_with_tag` method? As that is the one I need, and it needs to stay the same value in both methods.

Comment: As I don't know what your step does exactly it's hard to say how you could achieve that

Comment: @pjam i have updated it to show the last steps, the steps before this just simply take you to the page. I also removed some stuff, hopefully nothing vital.

Comment: also id like to add that this works if i hardcore `tag_list.should include @tag`'s instance variable. For example if i put `tag_list.should include "hard_coded"` everything then works as expected.

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but I was wondering what is the `on_page ` method actually doing ? is it one of your method or is it included in a lib you're using ?

Comment: `on_page` simply does something to the current page. `visit_page` visits the page in a page object class and then can do something. For example you could have `visit_page(Google)` and then have `on_page(Google).search` the first one would look for a `page_url` in the class `google` and go to it. and the second one would execute the method `search` in the class `Google` on the current page. [Click Here For Documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/cheezy/page-object/master/PageObject/PageFactory#on_page-instance_method)

Comment: But anyway, you just need to set the @tag before trying to read it. So for instance you could set it at the beginning of the `verify_last_tag ` method, or if you need it to be the same in both tests, you can take a look at : http://www.cloudspace.com/blog/2010/06/23/using-instance-variables-with-cucumber-steps/ I'm no expert with cucumber so I can't really help you.

Comment: @pjam i think this might be the fix and the correct way to do what i was trying to accomplish. Ill give it a try tomorrow, and if it is right ill let you know so you can post an answer and get your points.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18638/discussion-between-seldon-stone-and-pjam)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But anyway, you just need to set the @tag before trying to read it. So for instance you could set it at the beginning of the verify_last_tag  method, or if you need it to be the same in both tests, you can take a look at [that post](http://www.cloudspace.com/blog/2010/06/23/using-instance-variables-with-cucumber-steps/)
I'm no expert with cucumber so I can't really help you.